# VirtualBox 6.1.2 upgrade on Windows (host)

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Opening the *VirtualBox* application, pops up the upgrade dialog:

[image: Img00]

Unfortunately, **the *URL*** (https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.2/VirtualBox-6.1.2-135662-Win.exe) **is broken**. Following it (and thus opening in browser), yields:

[image: Img01]

**Additional info**:

- *OS*: *Win 10 (pc064)* (don't think that's relevant)
- Current *VirtualBox* version: *v6.1.0* (also, don't think that's relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Fix

Go one level up in the tree pointed by the *URL*, by removing the *Win* executable name that comes after the last *slash* ("***/***") - which is the selected part in the 2<sup>nd</sup> image form the question (in the address bar).

The new *URL* is: **[[VirtualBox.Download]: Index of /virtualbox/6.1.2](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.2)**

- Plain: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.2

Opening that in browser yields:

[image: Img00]

Click on the (selected) *Win* installer (***VirtualBox-6.1.2-135663-Win.exe***), and (download and) install it.

**Note**: I was able upgrade my existing installation to *v6.1.2*.

#### Investigation

The problem is that the *Win* executable build number was bumped to *13566**3*** after *135662* was published (I assumed because of a bug that turned out to be showstopper), but the displayed *URL* was not updated accordingly.

A bit of *Google* search revealed that my assumption was correct: there was a problem with the *Extension Pack* (*Guest Additions*) in the previous build (*135662*). References:

- [[VirtualBox.Forums]: Update 6.1.2-135662 ?](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=96419)
- [[VirtualBox.Forums]: UPDATE LEAVES Virtual Box UNUSABLE](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=96409)
- [[VirtualBox]: "NEWEST" Extension Pack 6.1.2 Install Failure (01-15-20)](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19225)

**Notes**:

- I was able to install the *Extension Pack* (I always download and import it manually into *VirtualBox*), and also install it in a ***Ubuntu*** (18 pc064) **guest**:

  > ```bash
  > [cfati@cfati-ubtu18pc064-00:~]> uname -m
  > x86_64
  > [cfati@cfati-ubtu18pc064-00:~]> cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DESCR
  > DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
  > [cfati@cfati-ubtu18pc064-00:~]>
  > [cfati@cfati-ubtu18pc064-00:~]> modinfo vboxguest
  > filename:       /lib/modules/5.0.0-37-generic/misc/vboxguest.ko
  > version:        6.1.2 r135662
  > license:        GPL
  > description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux Module
  > author:         Oracle Corporation
  > srcversion:     9C2C88BA900361E5F1AC135
  > alias:          pci:v000080EEd0000CAFEsv00000000sd00000000bc*sc*i*
  > depends:        
  > retpoline:      Y
  > name:           vboxguest
  > vermagic:       5.0.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload
  > ```
- Not sure why it only applies to the *Win* binary, cause it definitely doesn't look like a platform dependent bug. Maybe the *Nix* binaries were updated using the (same) old build version

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems downloading Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.2.vbox-extpack from popup in Oracle Vitualbox the download the file got to Virtual website https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and download manualy.

If you cannot install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.2.vbox-extpack in VirtualBox-6.1.2-135662-Win.exe then do the following:

Re-install VirtualBox-6.1.0-135406-Win.exe 
Now install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.2.vbox-extpack.

It should install on VirtualBox-6.1.0-135406

Re-install VirtualBox-6.1.2-135662-Win.exe.

It will work now on VirtualBox-6.1.2-135662